# Designing A Flickering LEDs Circuit

Tags: led, schematics, 555

I'm currently designing a simple circuit for to fire 4 LEDs in such a way that they appear to flicker. I want each to appear appear to fire randomly and independent of one another. I wanted to accomplish this with a single 555 as the whole thing will be jammed into the body of Games Workshop Rhino model. I planned to use [Vishay TLHY4205](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2049567.pdf) LEDs and considered [multicomp PRO 2N4870](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2861196.pdf) transistors for this circuit. The whole thing will be powered by a 9V battery. What are some pitfalls of this design and what improvements could I make? Be gentle, I'm a software developer and mini painter, not an electronics engineer.[image: Circuit schematic]

Comment: At least look up some 555 timer examples. That may not work. If you can write software, you could use a MCU and drive the LEDs with pseudorandom noise to make them flicker seemingly at random.

Comment: `independent of one another` use independent sources of noise.

Comment: Add an LFSR (example 8 stages 74164 + some gates, wired as pseudo random) to the circuit.

Comment: A little PIC or ATtiny or similar will be more successful, smaller, cheaper, and modifiable. The circuit shown does not have much hope of working.

Comment: You can also just buy "candle flicker LEDs."

Comment: I did simulate it in multisim, it appears to work?